# How to say 'Can I continue studying Japanese?'

Tags: grammar, english-to-japanese, nominalization

How would I say the following:

> Can I continue studying Japanese?

I was thinking something along the lines of

> Watashi wa nihongo o narau no tsudukimasuka?

It's probably wrong, and I could use some help.

Comment: Are you using "can" in the sense of asking for permission (*tudukete mo ii desu ka*) or asking about the possibility (*tudukeraremasu ka*)?

Comment: It's more In a sense of permission I'd say

Answer (score 3):

There are three issues here.

1. #### Transitivity

   *tuduku* (→ *tudukimasu*) is intransitive ("to continue [of its own accord]"). You need its transitive sibling *tudukeru* "to continue [sth.]" (→ *tudukemasu*).
2. #### Translation of "Can/May I..."

   "Can/May I [verb]?" is usually translated using ～てもいいですか *-te mo ii desu ka*, here *tudukete mo ii desu ka*.
3. #### Grammar

   *nihongo wo narau no* is a noun phrase, which should become the object of *tudukeru*. To make this grammatical you would need another particle *wo*, giving *nihongo wo narau no **wo** tudukeru*. A way to avoid two *wo*s in the same sentence would be to substitute *narau no* by *benkyō*, for example. *nihongo no benkyō wo tudukeru*.

Putting everything together, I would suggest

> *nihongo no benkyō wo tudukete mo ii desu ka*

as an improved version of your sentence.

You haven't given any context, so we can't determine whether this is a natural way of phrasing this question in your context.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, and the detailed explanation. The basic context of the sentence Is that, I haven't been to class for the longest amount of time, and I was wondering If I can continue studying from where I left off. The message Is intended for the teacher.

Comment: There might be more elaborate ways to say something like "Can I continue studying Japanese from where I left off?", but for the context, I think the sentence you now have is fine, especially for a message from a (beginning) student to his/her teacher. (If you wait a few more hours/days you might get feedback from other people.)